# How to move compiled Python to another Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I have built Python 3.7 from source using this guide [Link](https://www.scivision.co/compile-install-python-beta-raspberry-pi/)

It took me 4 h to fully build it. And here comes my question. It's possible to make deb file or any way to move that Python 3.7 to another Raspberry Pi. Cause don't wanna need to compile it again. I've tried to use packages from the official Debian repository but they don't want to work correctly.

Comment: did the make generate a `build` directory?

Comment: I used that guide as in the link, not created build directory.

Comment: yes I know, but the reason why I am asking is because sometimes the `make` utility will generate a `build` directory with the output of the compilation, and if you have it, theoretically you can take the python binaries from there.

Comment: I have checked ~/cpython-3.7.1 directory and yes I can see directory build :)